# Need help for displaying message text with images as a list

Tags: android, imageview

I need to start an application that contains a list of text with images. I need to display these text messages in a list with images. I am displaying these messages with images by using linear layouts as shown below.

```
for(int i=0;i<messages.size();i++)
{
    FrameLayout f1= new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout l2 = new LinearLayout(this);
    im =new ImageView(this);
    TextView tv =new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(messages.get(i).getmessage());
    im.setImageResource(R.drawable.person);
    l1.addView(tv);
    l2.addView(im);
    f1.addView(l1);
    f1.addView(l2);
    ((LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearlayoutMessage)).addView(f1);
}
```

After some time I need to refresh only images in the image view. I am trying to do this by setting id's to each image view's but I get only last image view id.

I know there is listview, but is it suitable for my requirement? I don't know how can I do my task. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please add comment why down vote my question

Comment: [Android ListView and ListActivity - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) and [Custom ListView](http://pareshnmayani.wordpress.com/tag/android-custom-listview-example/) are examples of custom ListView with image and TextView which may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar.. I just did a list of TextViews (two TextView per row), and i needed to update one TextView in the list.. What i did was a vertical LinearLayout, and add Horizontal LinearLayouts that contained my TextViews.. Then i had a List of strings to look for the index of the one i needed to modify, and then search it with `LinearLayout.getChildAt(int)` and update the value...

CODE:
I have a list of strings and a counter that says how many times come this string...

```
private ArrayList<String> strList;
private ArrayList<Integer> counterList;
```

When the String is new:

```
strList.add(new_string);
TextView str = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
str.setText(sTemp);
str.setLayoutParams(strsTextView.getLayoutParams());
TextView strcounter = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
strcounter.setLayoutParams(counterTextView.getLayoutParams());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1);

LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
ll.addView(str, layoutParams);

layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,3);

counterList.add(1);
strcounter.setText("1");
ll.addView(strcounter, layoutParams);
mLinearLayout.addView(ll,new LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I check if the String is not new (is already in the strList)`if(strList.indexOf(sTemp)!=0)` and then do as follows:

```
Integer intaux =counterList.get(index);
intaux++;
counterList.set(index, intaux);
LinearLayout aux = (LinearLayout)mLinearLayout.getChildAt(index);
TextView aux2 = (TextView)aux.getChildAt(1);
aux2.setText(Integer.toString(intaux));
```

I hope i didn't miss anything and that this works for you.. If you don't understand anything tell me an i try to explain/correct it.

PS: I suppose that the Adapter solution of @abhijeet is a more elegant version of my implementation, but i haven't done it.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use Adapter for showing image and respective text. It will help you get selected/focused item.

Please share result.